# AngularJS ng-model is updating only after click on input, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got weird problem with binding data in angular, I have an input file and if file is selected then his title should display in input below. It's displaying, but only if I click on this input. It should be displayed automatically after I select file from file input form, here is some code:

.html:

```
<div class="md-button md-raised md-primary raised-button">
<label class="ng-binding" for="image-file">UPLOAD FILE</label>
</div>

<md-input-container>
<div class="raised">
 <input id="image_file_name" type="text" ng-model="vm.filename"></input>
 </div>    
</md-input-container>

<input ng-model="vm.filename" style="display: none" id="image-file"   type="file" 
on-upload="uploadFile"/>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('imageController', function($scope, fileService) {

$('.intro-for-image').show(2000);

 $scope.uploadFile = function(event){
    $scope.event = event;
  fileService.uploadFile($scope);
};

});
```

directive:

```
app.directive('onUpload', function() {
 return {
restrict: 'A',
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  var onChangeFunc = scope.$eval(attrs.onUpload);
  element.bind('change', onChangeFunc);
}
};
});
```

service:

```
angular.module('app')
.service('fileService', function ($http,  validationService) {

      this.uploadFile = function ($scope) {
        var event = $scope.event;
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        name = file.name;

        $scope.vm = {
            file: file,
            filename: name,
        };
    }; 
});
```

I'm not sure about this directive, I found it somewhere after I googled my earlier problem.

Comment: Hi! Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227788/get-source-and-name-of-selected-file-with-angularjs

Comment: This might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file

Comment: Same problem here, how did you solve it?